# How do I parse the below dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, javascriptserializer

I have a json which is badly formatted. I want to take out the status and order id from that json. Tried JSON parsing with object, but did not get the result. Please help,
My Json,

```
    {
        "formname": [
            "Sale_Order_API",
            {
                "operation": [
                    "add",
                    {
                        "values": {
                            "Order_ID": "1250",
                            "Email": "xyz@yws.in",
                            "Order_Value": "100",
                            "Restaurant_Name": "HiTech",

                            "Order_Date": "13-Aug-2019",

                        },
                    "status": "Failure, Duplicate values found for 

    'Order ID'"
                    }
               ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Please help.
This is my first question , please ignore mistakes.

I have tried something like this, But not able to get the inner values

```
dynamic resultdata = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(postData);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Is what you wrote as the JSON exactly how it is in your code, defined as a string without double quotes?

Comment: I have not got any error. Just clueless how to do the next step. This is the exact json which I have received from an api.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't get the result"? What happened when you parsed the JSON?

Comment: You didn't get an error parsing invalid JSON?  That's difficult to believe.  Your JSON doesn't pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to deserialize this JSON. On 'http://json2csharp.com/#' you can generate a C # class from your JSON. Or right by your own. There are plenty of tutorials on the Internet. In case your class, where you give the values of the Json, is called 'JSONResult', you could access the values as follows

```
var resultdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONResult>(postData);

JSONResult outPut = resultdata;

Console.WriteLine(outPut.formname[0]);
```

But the longer I look at the format of your JSON, the more confused I get. Where did you get the JSON from? From an API?

Comment: If you're using visualstudio you could just do Edit -> paste special -> Paste JSON As Classes